# remove apache tar binary package in centos

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos

I need help in removing binary package that had been installed in my linux machine.
The scenario that I am having are such as like this:

I've already install latest apache that I get from its website(httpd.apache.org) through Unix binary package(tar.gz)

After successfully install program,the apache server web perfectly without any issues.

But then I having a thought,if there are another latest release version of apache in the future,then I need to make sure that i can upgrading current apache or reinstalling the new version apache.

So my question is, how do I ensure that I have remove the old apache and all its dependencies so that it will not having conflict(probably) when installing the new apache.

Right now the only thing that i can think of is to remove all the apache folder manually :

```
rm -rf /apache2
```

Hope someone can shed some light about this.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you just delete the folder, populate a new one and it should work, if all the files are there (don't forget to make a backup of the configs).

If you just want it to work, there's no need for deleting at all. The new binaries will overwrite the old. You only have to be careful about configs (not overwriting old=good=configured ones with default="empty". There might be some leftover files, but except for a couple of megs of extra used space, there's nothing to worry about.

The proper way to manage all that, is to create a package compatible with your package manager, and let it worry about un/installs. If you have a .deb/.rpm style distribution, check out [checkinstall](http://asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/).

Comment: Good advice.but still, i am hoping there's a way to remove the program without the need to do so much hassle.like a uninstall script maybe?which work in the centos.

Comment: Centos uses rpm packages. If all you did was untar it into a dir, and then started it, deleting the dir will do. If you ran an install script, i really suggest making a package. BTW, what is wrong with the apache provided by centos in it's package repositories?

Comment: i know centos are providing the apache by using yum but the version is not the same with the current (stable release) in the apache official website.so i figure out to install it by binary package rather than relying on centos package repositories.

Comment: centos and apache have different standards for >stable<. When it works for apache, it's "stable" for them. Then the RedHat/centos team tests it, and when they're satisfied with it (and it's centos integration), then they mark it as stable too. I'd use the centos version, since it's easier to update and manage. Dont worry about stability, it's stable :)

Comment: oh really?but how about security fix?like bug or patches,etc...

Comment: Yes, the security fixes etc are included and it's updated through the centos package management (you still have to update it regullary, like the rest of the system with yum).